# Use pine to evaluate trades from multiple pairs on CSV

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I have a bunch of trades already performed on a CSV. It contains their time, type (buy/sell), amount, pair, price and other data.

How can I insert this data on pine to evaluate the trades on the graph, taking into account there are multiple pairs?

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible to import external data into a pinescript for now

Comment: Would you happen to know another program where I could do this?